# Keyword for functions in C++?

Tags: c++, function, parsing, keyword, language-design

Why doesn't C++ have a keyword to define/declare functions? Basically all other design abstractions in the language have one (`struct`, `class`, `concept`, `module`, ...).

Wouldn't it make the language [easier to parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), as well as more consistent? Most "modern" languages seem to have gone this way (`fn` in rust, `fun` in kotlin, ...).

Comment: You mean, besides parenthesis in declaration?

Comment: yes, having an actual keyword to make it explicit.

Comment: Probably for consistency with variables?

Comment: If you like you can use `#define function ` and then `function int foo(){...};` :-)

Comment: And the [IOCCC](https://www.ioccc.org/) 2020 award goes to @schorsch312 ...

Comment: C++ inherits the approach to declare functions from C.   The design of C often prioritised ability to achieve brevity of code, even if it is debatable whether that is a good idea, so tends to avoid code constructs (including keywords) that can be avoided.   C (particularly in recent standards) is moderately difficult to parse, and C++ is significantly more difficult to parse - and adding a keyword to make function declarations easier to parse would not have a big (relative) benefit in terms of making parsing easier.

Comment: Parsing function definitions is not hard. What makes C++ parsing hard (in fact Turing complete) is templates. Consider this: `template<bool x, class C> void foo(C &c){ if(x) c.push_back(0); else c.push_back(1); }` and its invocation in `template<class C, int a, int b> void bar(C &c){ foo<a<b>(c); }` A parser has to wonder if each angled bracket is part of a template instanciation, or an operator.

Comment: C++14 gave us `auto square(int a) { return a * a; }`, so there *is* a keyword for declaring functions. C++20 may give us `auto square(arithmetic auto a) { return a * a; }` for (constrained) templates

Comment: There's no keyword for variable declarations and definitions either. And the distinction between variables and constants isn't very clean either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++'s Syntax comes mostly from C and C doesn't provide a `function` keyword. Instead, it uses a certain syntax to indicate most functions:

```
[return type] [function name]([paramters]) { }
```

So if a `function` keyword was introduced, we could gain faster parsing and improve readibility. However, you would now have 2 different ways to declare something and you can'
t get rid of the old way due to the backwards compability necessity.

---

But let's assume we ignore the backwards compability argument and suppose it was introduced:

```
function int square(int a) { //1
    return a * a; 
} 

//-----------------------------

function square(int a) { //2
    return a * a; 
}
```

case `1` simply behaves like a keyword indicator, which has upsides (readiblity, parsing) and downsides (spamming the function declarations with unnecessary noise)

case `2` is a javascript-esque approach, letting the compiler figure out the return type (like `auto` here). it is probably the most esthetic approach, but C++ is very static typed and this would add a layer of confusion when it's not needed (`auto`-ness can be useful, but is certainly not always wanted).

---

So in the end it seems like these medium benefits just didn't justify the cost that would have came with introducing such a keyword.

---

extra bit:

since C++11 the language features would allow you to argue for a perticular approach:

```
function square(int a) -> int { 
    return a * a; 
}
```

and this would certainly be a pretty solid solution! But it seems like the discussion about a `function` keyword has long subsided. Which is understandable when there are many other, probably more important, priorities to discuss while innovating on the newest C++ releases.

Answer (score 4):

Well, despite being a sort of a modern language (at least, I think that C++17 IS a modern language, but this is IMHO), C++ has to carry the backward compatibility with most of the C and C++ versions that were created in the past 50 years or so. At that time it was completely new field of work, no one really knew how to do it better. It was 1978! C creators thought that this would be enough, its completely their decision.

Implementing new keywords now would break existing code, so I don't think its okay to do that.

Modern languages like Rust, Kotlin and others had an impeccable amount of time to consider what is good and what is not based on currently existing languages, those that were used in the past and then disappeared, etc.

To be honest, I think that current syntax is pretty okay and nothing needs to be done about it.

Most vexing parse, of course, is a problem, but a well-known one to nearly everyone that uses C++.

Answer (score 0):

Because functions are identified in an another way: via parentheses after their name. Note that functions came from `C` which didn't have those design abstractions mentioned. Therefore, adding an odd keyword wouldn't had aided sticking to a certain language design. Moreover, having one less reserved word is not a bad thing.

If you really want a function keyword, you can do this:

```
#define FUNC auto
FUNC foo() -> Bar {
  baz();
}
```

Comment: This suggestion is much like adding `#define BEGIN {`, `#define END }`, and others like that. Doing it in an actual project means that new people that will come to this project would need to learn sort of a new language based on already known one... Please, don't do it outside your home pet projects :-D

Comment: Using defines to mimic behavior of other languages is a relly bad idea.

Comment: @Simon it's surely bad but alright in your small local projects.